# Presenting a web application while offline

Tags: offline, web-browser

I have a web application that I need to present, but I have no internet connection in the presentation place.

Is there an existing piece of software to make my application look like it's online?

I don't want to display video. I want a means to simulate my app through software.

From some googling I found some software prototype like [Marvel](https://marvelapp.com/prototype-with-sketch/), but it works online.

Comment: Running a local server?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: See also this question ("Can you convert html, css and javascript into a exe?"): http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14797/can-you-convert-html-css-and-javascript-into-a-exe/

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with Steve that you are probably going to need a server, however,  I have found that people can have trouble setting up and using Apache. And even when they do, they may still need to install MySql.

What you need is a [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server. One of the most popular is [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). I have been recommending  it for years and, more importantly, using it for years to do just what you want to (additionally, I do all of my web development locally, not on my actual website and this facilitates that).

It will give you an Apache server (already configured), plus PHP and MySql if you need them (a few other things too, which I don't use).

If you install to the default location, then the server `localhost` will be at C:\xampp\htdocs. Just copy your stuff there and point your browser at, for instance, `http://localhost/index.html`.

If you want to use your files in their current directory, then you need to change the server root in a configuration file as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847392/how-to-change-xampp-localhost-to-another-folder-outside-xampp-folder).

It is really all quite simple, but feel free to ask questions if it is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not too reliant on server side processing you can simply:

1. Download/Install to your PC the same directory structure as would exist on your server.
2. Open your browser and set it to **file:**//*Where/You/Put/It/index.html*

For a simple web server start with 1. above, install [python](http://python.org) and in a command window, `cd` to the top directory above and enter `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` then open your browser and browse to `http://localhost:8000` or for an app that relies on CGI processing you can use the CGIHTTPServer module.

Other than that I would suggest running a full web server such as Apache on your demo machine, (much easier under Linux).