# free tool to make a web application record and presentation

Tags: windows, web-apps, offline, presentation

I would like a free open source tool (windows compatible if possible) that make me easy to record and present offline a web application.
Until today I was using [wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) that produce an executable. It's not a bad tool but seems no more maintained ? maybe a little bit outdated (form) ?

Does exist a better tool for :

- screen capture;
- screen sequence capture
- audio recording,
- annotation/draw against presentation
- produce a friendly format to (re)play the presentaion

Note that I don't want to install a web server or a mock of the application but create a standalone executable presentation (avi/exe/..).

Comment: Similar question: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/presenting-a-web-application-while-offline

Comment: @DanCornilescu I don't want to install a local webserver and I dont't want to browse my application locally but just a tool to record a given scenario to present it later (like a video or an enhanced slideshow).

Comment: @DanCornilescu difference between the two questions: Lola (over there) wants to dynamically present the application (live-interaction) – while boly here wants to create a "cast" to be presented even in absence of the author ;) So ***close-voters:*** that question is a close relative, but no duplicate. I vote to "leave open".

Comment: We're in agreement, I just mentioned the other question as a *potential* alternative if no (better) answer shows up. Turns out it's not for this case, might be for others. Should I remove my comment?