# HTML5, JS and CSS export to standalone desktop app

Tags: windows, osx, javascript, html

For the beginning, I know there are questions like this already, but they are all outdated and all apps that people recommended doesn't exist or don't work. So, is there any new app like tideSDK or something that can just simply export html code to (if possible cross platform) app. Windows or Mac? I know there is AppJs but it is a little complicated to use and it isn't clean. Also I think nw isn't good enough too. So does anyone know any good program that can do that? If possible with GUI.

Comment: What do you mean with *export HTML code to an app*? Please [edit]. And adding some links to the products you mention would be nice too.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Moreover: Links to those "outdated questions" (uh? Our site is just a little over a year old!) might be helpful as well.

Comment: Related: [Can you convert html, css and javascript into a exe?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14797/185)

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Electron](http://electron.atom.io) a try. Applications like Visual Studio Code, Atom, and Slack have been built with it, and (in my experience) those apps are quite impressive and stable.

The link I provided has a list of software built with Electron, as well as a getting started guide further down the page.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called Scriptonit. I created it to have something for quick utility development for myself, like assistants, listers, specific file search tools, code banks, backup engines, documenting systems; after more than 30 of these little powertools, I can safely say it's worth trying.

https://scriptonit.dk

is the official domain, I usually buy dk domains because of my name. So please feel free to try, here are some pros and cons:

#### Pros

- It's lightweight
- No compilation
- Practically no load time
- Hot reload
- Very simple config
- Smallest example is 3 files
- Easy to learn
- Good example projects
- There's a doc (and it's written in Scriptonit itself)

#### Cons:

- IE11 under the hood, aka WebView 1
- You have flexbox but no grids
- Your source is visible
- No ready-made fancy frameworks
- Windows only (until someone compiles a version for Mac)

Welcome to this world, I literally live in it and it's super enjoyable.